# How to Configure Spring Boot with Memcached

Tags: java, caching, spring-boot, memcached

I am new to Memcached. I need to configure my spring boot application with Memcached.

I researched a lot on the topic but I could not find a documentation for the same.
By default Spring boot uses Concurrent HashMap for caching but how do I configure Memcached.

I got this GitHub URL but I am not sure if this is the correct way and if so how do I use the same.

https://github.com/sixhours-team/memcached-spring-boot

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/simple-spring-memcached-spring-caching-abstraction-and-memcached.html

Update

I have used this in my project now https://github.com/bmatthews68/memcached-spring-boot-starter.

Like this

```
@Override @Cacheable(value = "defaultCache")
    public String customMethof() throws InterruptedException {
        return "Testing";
    }
```

but when i do a telnet of get defaultCache i get nothing  Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your Gradle Dependencies

```
compile group: 'net.spy', name: 'spymemcached', version: '2.12.3'
compile('com.btmatthews.springboot:memcached-spring-boot-starter:1.0.0')
```

On top of your main Spring boot application where you `@SpringBootApplication`this annotation put this

```
@EnableMemcached
```

Then in your Component use the following

```
@Autowired
private MemcachedClient memcachedClient;

memcachedClient.get("...")
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm one of the authors of the https://github.com/sixhours-team/memcached-spring-boot. 
The library will auto-configure Memcached within a Spring Boot application. You can enable it just as you would with Spring Cache i.e. it is sufficient to add the `@EnableCaching` annotation in your configuration class e.g.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration {
}
```

The configuration in the `application.yml` can be as simple as:

```
memcached.cache:
   servers: example1.com:11211
   mode: static
   expiration: 86400
```

At the moment, the library has not been released yet (the first release should be in about a week). You can find more info [here](https://github.com/sixhours-team/memcached-spring-boot/blob/master/README.md) or check the demo Spring Boot app [here](https://github.com/sixhours-team/spring-boot-memcached-demo-kotlin).

One more thing, in order to support cache **eviction**, the library is prefixed with `memcached:spring-boot:defaultCache:[radnom_number]`, so in your case the key would be something like e.g.

`memcached:spring-boot:books:defaultCache:283:SimpleKey[]`

where **283** is the random number assigned to the cache key (needed for the proper cache eviction).

Comment: @CCC Currently not, but we are working on version 2.0, and this is something that might be included with the this release.

Comment: I'm planning in using Memcache for a large project under GCP and found this one to be maybe the most complete out there, so that would be awesome. When are you planning on releasing v 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

The first GitHub project you have shown is a good solution. It is also a fork a spymemcached which is one of the prominent client libraries of Memcached.

Please refer the below official documentation.
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_caching

You can also check the below one and traverse to Getting Started page.

https://github.com/killme2008/xmemcached

Comment: updated the question can you please check once thanks